# How to sumarize correctly: "Total Time" + "Sickness Time" + "Vacation Time" - mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, sum

In mysql database i've created "Sickness" table:

```
+--------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+---------------+
| Id_SICK|ID_WORKER| FNAME   | LNAME   | BEGIN_DATE          | END_DATE              | SICKNESS_TIME |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+------------+--------------------+-----------+---------------+
| 4      |   26    | ANDREW  | WORM    |2019-03-19 07:00:00  |2019-03-19 15:00:00    |    8:00:00    | 
+--------+---------+---------+----------------------+--------------------+-----------+---------------+  
| 5      |   25    | ADAM    | GAX     |2019-03-21 07:00:00  |2019-03-21 15:00:00    |    8:00:00    |
+--------+---------+---------+----------------------+--------------------------------+---------------+
```

, "Vacation" table:

```
+-------------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+---------------+
| ID_VACATION |ID_WORKER| FNAME   | LNAME   | BEGIN_DATE          | END_DATE              | VACATION_TIME |
+-------------+---------+---------+---------+------------+--------------------+-----------+---------------+
|      1      |   25    | ADAM    | GAX     |2019-03-19 07:00:00  |2019-03-19 15:00:00    |    8:00:00    | 
+-------------+---------+---------+----------------------+--------------------+-----------+---------------+  
|      2      |   26    | ANDREW  | WORM    |2019-03-21 07:00:00  |2019-03-21 15:00:00    |    8:00:00    |
+-------------+---------+---------+----------------------+--------------------------------+---------------+
```

"Workers" table:

```
+----------+---------+---------+
|ID_WORKER |  FNAME  | LNAME   |
+----------+---------+----------
| 25       |  ADAM   |  GAX    |
+----------+---------+----------
| 26       |  ANDREW |  WORM   |
+----------+---------+---------+
```

"Orders" table:

```
+----------+--------------+---------------+
|ID_ORDER  |  DESC_ORDER  | NUMBER_ORDER  |
+----------+--------------+---------------+
| 20       |  TEST        |  TEST         |
+----------+--------------+---------------+
```

"Order_status" table:

```
+----------+---------+---------+---------------------+-------------------+------------+
| Id_status|ID_WORKER| ID_ORDER| BEGIN_DATE          | END_DATE          | ORDER_DONE |
+----------+---------+---------+----------+------------+---------+--------------------+
| 47       |   25    |    20   |2019-03-18 06:50:35  |2019-03-18 15:21:32|  NO        |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+ 
| 48       |   25    |    20   |2019-03-20 06:44:12  |2019-03-20 15:11:23|  NO        |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+ 
| 50       |   25    |    20   |2019-03-22 06:50:20  |2019-03-22 12:22:33|  YES       |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+ 
| 51       |   26    |    20   |2019-03-18 06:45:11  |2019-03-18 15:14:45|  NO        |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+ 
| 52       |   26    |    20   |2019-03-20 06:50:22  |2019-03-20 15:10:32|  NO        |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+ 
| 53       |   25    |    20   |2019-03-22 06:54:11  |2019-03-22 11:23:45|  YES       |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+
```

What i've done:

I can to sumarize "total time" of each other workers (in order_status table) on the order including with sumarizing "sickness time" from Sickness table and "Vacation time" from Vacation table. I have selected workers (LNAME, FNAME) orders (DESC_ORDER and NUMBER_ORDER) and "TOTAL TIME" on order from each other workers correctly too. I wrote the mysql command in below:

```
SELECT workers.fname, 
       workers.lname, 
       order_statusAgg.number_order,
       order_statusAgg.desc_order, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(order_statusAgg.ttime)) AS 'TOTAL TIME', 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(sicknessAgg.stime)) AS 'SICKNESS TIME', 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(vacationAgg.vtime)) AS 'VACATION TIME' 
FROM   workers 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT sickness.id_worker, SUM((Time_to_sec(sickness.end_date) - 
                       Time_to_sec(sickness.begin_date))) AS stime
FROM sickness
GROUP BY sickness.id_worker
) sicknessAgg
               ON sicknessAgg.id_worker = workers.id_worker
       INNER JOIN (
SELECT order_status.id_worker, orders.number_order, orders.desc_order, SUM((Time_to_sec(order_status.end_date) - 
                       Time_to_sec(order_status.begin_date))) AS ttime
FROM order_status
           INNER JOIN orders 
               ON orders.id_order = order_status.id_order
GROUP BY order_status.id_worker
) order_statusAgg
               ON workers.id_worker = order_statusAgg.id_worker 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT vacation.id_worker, SUM((Time_to_sec(vacation.end_date) - Time_to_sec(vacation.begin_date))) AS vtime
FROM vacation
GROUP BY vacation.id_worker) vacationAgg 
ON vacationAgg.id_worker = workers.id_worker 
WHERE  order_statusAgg.number_order LIKE 'TEST'
GROUP BY workers.id_worker
```

Then result:

```
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
|  FNAME  | LNAME   |  NUMBER_ORDER | DESC_ORDER | TOTAL TIME | SICKNESS_TIME| VACATION_TIME| 
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
|  ADAM   |  GAX    | TEST          | TEST       | 22:30:21   |   8:00:00    |   8:00:00    |
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
|  ANDREW |  WORM   | TEST          | TEST       | 21:19:18   |   8:00:00    |   8:00:00    |
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

What i'd like to do next:
I'm trying sumarize all of them, i mean: TOTAL TIME + SICKNESS_TIME +  VACATION_TIME. For example: where ID_WORKER = 25

```
Vacaton_time = 8:00:00
Sick_time = 8:00:00
Total_time = 22:30:21
SUM_TIME = vacation_time + sick_time + Total_time
SUM_TIME = 8:00:00 + 8:00:00 + 22:30:21 = 38:30:21
```

i've tried add to at the top query:

```
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(order_statusAgg.ttime) + SUM(sicknessAgg.stime) + SUM(vacationAgg.vtime)) AS 'SUM_TIME';
```

But i know that's a bad idea. So i have no clue how to solve it.
Has someone idea how to solve it? Any ideas. Thx very much for any help!

Comment: Why not just have 1 'leave' table

Comment: It can be 'leave table' but why should be 1 'leave table' ?

Comment: Because holiday leave and sick leave are still both 'leave'.

Comment: ok, but each worker cannot have holiday leave and sick leave. Someone can get holiday leave or sick leave.

Comment: Really? Anyway, I still don't see why that matters!?! But maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Nope. You don't miss something